# Goloang Using Default mux, http.Fileserver producing invalid links. (similar to 46403678)

Tags: go, mux

Actually I'm having exactly the same symptom/issue as question 46403678:
The links returned are invalid.
The solution posted there appears to require the use of the Gorilla mux:

```
r.PathPrefix("/download/").Handler(
    http.StripPrefix("/download", http.FileServer(http.Dir(dirPath))),
).Methods("GET")
```

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require importing any 3rd party packages.

Comment: The [answer you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46404016/11810946) provides a "simple file server app using only the standard library" at the end that appears to address your question? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27946132/11810946) provides additional info. It will be easier to help you if you post [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The example you mention is what I have been working with.  The generated html links still do not include the containing directory in the path (as per the original question), however, by adding a second handler for "/dl/" I now have a functioning example.

Comment: I'm a little confused as the example has a handler for `/dl/` (`http.Handle("/dl/",...`). Glad you have found a solution but if ask another question please include your code (this makes it easier to answer and also means the answers are more likely to be of use to others).

Comment: to clarify:  I created two handlers, one for the "/dl" and one for the "/dl/", using the same code, to achieve the desired results.  Criticism understood and accepted.  I'm new to this environment and UI, I hope to improve over time.